# Python db lost connection middle of processing and parsing a huge log file

Tags: python, connection

I have a huge log file ~4 GB. I have to parse a log file line by line, for each line I should query database, and also connect to another csv files and join data from different sources. 
Execution time is near 2 days. However unfortunately for any reasons like lost connection to MySQL server during query, i've lost all the parsing so far and i have to run the script again and again. Then, During last one week I have executed this script several time and i've lost all the previous parsing. the script had to write the final result into csv file. I am looking for a solution to avoid of this problem, what can I do? 
Is there any way to keep the last status of the process somewhere in order I re-execute from the last point of process rather that running from the beginning each time? or any other solution that can avoid of this interruption.

Comment: My idea: Do not load full database at once, fetch for example 50 at once

Comment: How can I do that, in each line it extract the username and they query db to extract user info. Do u mean i save list of username and then query for 50 user names?!

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood question (I tought that you are reading from DB, not saving into). However: maybe remebering last processed line number would help? You could save this number into a file and in case of crash resume from that row? For csv file it would be easy to skip n rows

Comment: How big is the User data that you query from DB? If it is relatively small, cache it locally like in-memory or redis.

Comment: No, actually it's log file, in each like connect two 2 sources, one is db and another on is anther csv file.  After parsing all the log then I call csv module to write into csv, however the problem is that is not reaching never to the end so It never call the function to write info csv file.

Comment: @ArunDhaJ  user data it's only country, so I query db to extract country name associated to each user name.

Comment: `Welcome to the world of data management.` You lose everythings  with create a file out of system limits ! First rule of communication : **Never use a timer if haven't any idea about response time**, try multiple cursor with response timer.

Comment: Without seeing examples its difficult, but I would be inclined to parse files in python and insert data back to database tables and do all processing there, then output results and do whatever in python.

Comment: So, in your case, don't hit DB for every line. Query data first time and cache it. Also, use libraries like pandas to load your csv file as a DataFrame. Obviously, don't load entire CSV into one DataFrame, have some logic to split it to few DataFrame. Because, working with DataFrame is quite easier.

Comment: Yes, i like the idea. I have to query table ones and maybe convert to dictionary and then look up dictionary. This is more reasonable. this means by cashing as you commented?

Comment: @dsgdfg I did not use timer. what do u mean exactly by multiple cursor?

Comment: If you found a solution to the problem, you can _post an answer_ to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To solve above problem regarding to **above** discussion I have queried once db, I keep it as dictionary and then each time I get key in dictionary. It speeds up the time execution, more over lost connection is not going to affect anymore the processing. I would like to mention that Time execution is reduced to 20 min. It's incredible!! Thanks to dictionary ..